# Using jQuery to add 2 elements at once using selector syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to dynamically insert combo buttons in a loop. Right now I have the  tag successfully getting added, but I also want a line break (`<br/>`) after each one. How can I accomplish this? Here is what I have so far:

```
    var input = $('<input>', {
        type: "radio",
        name: "phone-format-radio",
        value: i+1,
        text: GetDisplayNumber( format )
    });

    $(id + ' > button').before( input );
```

the 'id' variable is the ID of my `<section>` element which contains my dynamically created `<input>` elements. There is also a `<button>` element inside of my `<section>` that is defined in the HTML file and must always remain the last child in my `<section>` (which is why I use .before().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `after`:

```
input.after('<br/>');
```